# Pass Arraylist as value from Mapper to reducer in Hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, mapper, reducers

I am working on a project which requires to pass data and have an **Arraylist** to be used as a value emitted in pair from the **Mapper** and collected in the **reducer**.

So, I wrote a **custom data-type** class implementing the Writable Interface and use it to pass the **arraylist** but I am facing problems to implement the same.

Comment: Post your errors and few code of your custom class.It will be easy for others to identify your issue

Comment: kindly review the code at the location:-http://www.codesend.com/view/7f06d1a1a12512203732577c7a648ec4/